# VB script to find a particular string in text file and move the text file to another path

Tags: vbscript

I need a VBs to find (string) "ERROR" from my alert log.txt and if the alert log.txt has error string , the that particular log must be moved to another specified location .
Am totally new to VBs, so please do help me....

this is code wich i used(googled it)..

```
Option Explicit 
'* 
Const ForWriting = 8

'* 
Dim strGFI, objFSO1, objOutputFile 
Dim strOTF, MyString, objFileSystem 
Dim strWSE, strWritePath, objFile 
Dim strInput, cFOL, StrDirectory

'* 
cFOL = "C:\temp\"
strInput = Inputbox("Enter the text you would like to search for.")

MyString = "Workstation"
strWritePath = "c:\text" & MyString & ".txt"
strDirectory = "C:\temp\"

Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO1.FileExists(strWritePath) Then
  'Wscript.Echo "The file Exists" 
Else
  Set objFile = objFSO1.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & MyString & ".txt")
  objFile = ""
End If

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & MyString & ".txt", ForWriting)

If cFOL > "" Then
  If strInput > "" Then
    Dim objFSO 
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Dim objGFO 
    Set objGFO = objFSO.GetFolder(cFOL) 
    Dim objGFI 
    Set objGFI = objGFO.Files 
    For Each strGFI in objGFI 
      Dim objOTF 
      Set objOTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(cFOL & "\" & strGFI.Name,1) 
      Do While Not objOTF.AtEndOfStream 
        strOTF = objOTF.ReadAll() 
      Loop 
      objOTF.Close() 
      Set objOTF = Nothing 
      '* 
      If  InStr(LCase(strOTF), strInput) > 0 Then 
        strWSE = strWSE & strGFI.Name & " contains " & strInput & vbCrLf
      Else 
        strWSE = strWSE & strGFI.Name & " Does not contain: " & strInput & vbCrLf 
      End If 
    Next 
    objOutputFile.WriteLine(strWSE)
    objOutputFile.Close

    '* 
    Set objGFI = Nothing 
    Set objGFO = Nothing 
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFileSystem = Nothing
    Set objFSO1 = Nothing

    '* 
    WScript.Echo strWSE
  Else
    Wscript.Echo "You Clicked Cancel or no search string was defined."
  End If
Else
  Wscript.Echo "You Clicked Cancel or no search path was defined."
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

Here it asks dynamically for d string to be identified. I want it to be static.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8).

Comment: i hav used a code wich is too long to paste here...

Comment: Then show relevant excerpts from your code, i.e. those parts you have problems with.

Comment: hav added the code...

Comment: There is only one place in the script where it asks for user input. Look for the string that is displayed and replace the `InputBox` with the string you want to search for.

Comment: Even if you new to VBScript, this is very, very simple. Just look for the place where the script asks for the search string. Just try it!

Answer (score 0):

because your input comes from the user, you must convert it lower case, simply because your test to see if the user text exists uses lower case.

So change the following line.

```
If  InStr(LCase(strOTF), strInput) > 0 Then
```

to

```
If  InStr(LCase(strOTF), LCase(strInput)) > 0 Then
```