# Find String inside Files and generate report

Tags: windows, vba, powershell, search, vbscript

I need to search for a particular string in my system.

I will provide a filepath

The program should search a predefined string in that filepath which may contain multiple folders and files with different extension.
It should then generate a .txt report with the filenames along with their filepath that contains that string(if possible even line number)

I have found a [similar article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233278/vb-script-to-find-a-particular-string-in-text-file-and-move-the-text-file-to-ano), but it only searches the defined path with files. It does not recursively go through the folders located inside that path and again search for it.

Comment: I referred to the code mentioned in the link. I used it but it doesnt search for folder inside the path; rest was good

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /s /m /l /c:"searchString" "c:\somewhere\*" > outputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell solution:

```
$filePath = "c:\"
$searchString = "test"
$outputFilePath = "c:\searchResults.txt"

Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | Select-String $searchString | select Path, LineNumber | Out-File $outputFilePath -Force
```